# AngularTS how to set input variable in HTML as true/false?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have the html:

```
<tag-input fullWidth id="inputDir" formControlName="inputDir" [modelAsStrings]="true"
                            [placeholder]="'choice feature'"
                            [allowDupes]="falseVariable"
                            [secondaryPlaceholder]="'choice feature'">
                            <tag-input-dropdown [showDropdownIfEmpty]="true" [autocompleteItems]="inputDirAutoComplete">
                            </tag-input-dropdown>

</tag-input>
```

I want to set `allowDupes` as false. It worked when I set as `falseVariable`, which I give false value in .ts

`falseVariable = false;`

However, if I set false into HTML, it does not work

```
<tag-input fullWidth id="inputDir" formControlName="inputDir" [modelAsStrings]="true"
                            [placeholder]="'choice feature'"
                            [allowDupes]="'false'"
                            [secondaryPlaceholder]="'choice feature'">
                            <tag-input-dropdown [showDropdownIfEmpty]="true" [autocompleteItems]="inputDirAutoComplete">
                            </tag-input-dropdown>

</tag-input>
```

What did I miss ?

(the library in example is `import { TagInputModule } from 'ngx-chips';`)

Comment: have you tried just `"false"` instead of `"'false'"`

Answer (score 1):

`allowDupes` is a boolean variable, not `string` variable.

On second code snippet, you have assigned `string` variable instead of `boolean` variable.

Please replace `[allowDupes]="'false'"` to `[allowDupes]="false"` and it will work.